# Cannot run Mathematica C-interfacing examples 'factor'

Tags: functions, mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I am trying to run a Mathematica example concerning Mathematica interfacing issues with C programs. In particular I am trying to call a Mathematica function from C.

Example `factor.c` is the best in my case. As explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Unix.html#24335) at the *Invoking the Mathematica Kernel from Within a Prebuilt Example* section, I successfully build the examples (using the makefile through `make all`). After that I run the exaple as explained by typing:

```
./factor -linkmode launch -linkname 'math -mathlink'
```

But I get back to my shell after launching the program with no output as I did nothing. Then I try again just by launching `./factor`, the program then asks me: `Create link:`, so I type `'math -mathlink'`, prfess ok, then it prompts: `Integer to factor:`, I type a 6 digit one and after that the program blocks (it waits for something, but after 5 minutes I kill it).

Consider that I am on Unix. My Mathematica installation is in this path `/home/myuser/progs/Mathematica...`. I run the example respectively with Mathematica running and not running. Same results.

How to make the example work?

#### Something strange

When I kill theprograms that I launch but stay on wait as I described before, it seems that they finally got killed, but it is not! When I try `ps` on my shell, they are there!!! Need to send `SIGKILL` to definetely get rid of them...

#### About links...

I bumped into a Mathematica function called [LinkCreate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinkCreate.html). Maybe I need to run Mathematica, open a link from the interface, and then launch the example? I am trying some, so far no results, will keep on doing so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you.  Try using the full path to the kernel executable.  The following works for me on OS X:

```
./factor -LinkMode Launch -LinkName '/Applications/Mathematica\ 9.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel'
```

I do have a symlink to `MathKernel` in a location that's in the `PATH`, but if I use that, as in `./factor -LinkMode Launch -LinkName math`, it doesn't work here either.  `./factor -LinkMode Launch -LinkName ~/bin/math` (i.e. giving the full path) does work.

---

If you want to start Mathematica separately (e.g. for understanding better what happens), do this:

Launch `factor` and at the `Create link:` prompt type any name.  For this example, let's use `mylink` as the link name.

Then launch Mathematica in another terminal as `math`.  Type `link = LinkConnect["mylink"]`.  If it worked, type `$ParentLink = link`.  Now you can use `factor`:  type the number you want to factor and press enter.

Comment: You are my savior... did not know it was possible to do this way. Thanks a lot, for real!!!